# Tomcat webapp silently fails

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat webapp that uses Hibernation Configuration, the code below silently fails 
at `Configuration cfg = new Configuration();`  Tomcat logs are not giving any error except my debugging statement right below where it fails (BEGIN STATIC!!!).  No exception is thrown.

However when I packed the app into a jar, and runs the same method call in the main, it succeeds without error.

```
public class Manager {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Manager.class);
    public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(getSessionFactory());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        if(sessionFactory==null){
        System.out.println("BEGIN STATIC!!!!!!!! ");

        try{
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); //FAILS SILENTLY
            System.out.println("BEGIN STATIC1"); //NOT PRINTED THEREAFTER
            cfg.configure("hibernate_xxx.xml");
            System.out.println("BEGIN STATIC2");
            cfg.addResource("xxx/persistence/xxx.xml");
            System.out.println("BEGIN STATIC 3");
            cfg.addResource("xxx/persistence/xxx.hbm.xml");
            cfg.addResource("xxx/persistence/xxx.hbm.xml");
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        }catch(Exception exp){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            exp.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }



        System.out.println("END STATIC ");
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following after your other catch:

```
catch(Error e){
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Probably an error was thrown instead of an exception.  Then at least you should get an error message instead of nothing.

Comment: turns out that the logging to file was lagging, the Exception showed up later a Hibernate related exception.